# Is there a close tab shortcut in PgAdmin 4?

Tags: pgadmin, pgadmin-4

Is there a shortcut to close a `View Data` tab in PgAdmin 4 (v5.0) ?

Ctrl+W doesn't work for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "File" -> "Reset Layout" which will reset the layout and close all tabs in the process. Not perfect but it does the trick.

Comment: Is there any keyboard shortcut that will work?  I am trying to script a database drop and need to close all the tabs first to close the DB connections.